# Add new object to ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, foursquare

I have venues in my database that a user can query, this of course yields an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

Sometimes there aren't enough venues in the area the user is searching from, so I want to pad it with `Foursquare` results from their API. Since these results are in a different format than my venues I decided to convert them to my `Venue` object and add them to the result of the query, but whatever I try seems to fail. This is the relevant block of code:

```
@venues = @venues.limit(30)
if @venues.count(:all) < 30
  foursquare_client = foursquare_client()
  fq_venues = foursquare_client.explore_venues(ll: params[:ll], radius: 1000, limit: 30 - @venues.count(:all), section: 'food')
  for item in fq_venues.groups[0].items
    fq_venue = item.venue
    location = Location.build_from_foursquare(fq_venue)
    @venues.build(name: fq_venue.name, foursquare_id: fq_venue.id, location: location)
  end
end
```

After this `@venues` doesn't contain the newly created `Venue` objects. I've also tried using the `<<` to add it to the `Relation` but that also didn't work. Any idea how I can manage this? Different approaches to my problem are also welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Convert `@venues` to array and add to array. `@venues.build` will return you a new object. but it will not automatically add to the collection.

```
@venues = @venues.limit(30)
if @venues.all.count < 30 #this converts @venues to array
  foursquare_client = foursquare_client()
  fq_venues = foursquare_client.explore_venues(ll: params[:ll], radius: 1000, limit: 30 -     @venues.count(:all), section: 'food')
  for item in fq_venues.groups[0].items
    fq_venue = item.venue
    location = Location.build_from_foursquare(fq_venue)
    @venues << @venues.build(name: fq_venue.name, foursquare_id: fq_venue.id, location: location)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now something I don't get is that before I was doing @venues << Venue.new... And it didn't work, but this somehow did when it's the same thing.

Comment: Its not the same thing. before it was an `ActiveRelation` object. Now its an `array`. I think it will try to save the object in database when you use `<<` on ActiveRelation object

Comment: No it doesn't, and that line to convert to array wasn't necessary just the part for `@venues << @venues.build`. I don't need it as an array since there are other concatenated queries that might happen after this.

Comment: actually I took a closer look and this seems to actually not have worked. I'm still getting an empty relation as a result.

Comment: @8vius Did this get solved as I have hit a similar issue for which I am looking for a solution?

Comment: @rctneil nope, forgot to unmark it, you pretty much have to turn the resulto into an array to do what this answer tells you, in that case it works. If you're not doing anything with the result afterwards it would suit the needs, if you need to keep concatenating queries to it then no.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Yes I need to chain further queries onto it. Ah well.  Thanks.